# Why does number field comes as Decimal type even if Decimal places is 0 in field definition

Tags: apex, custom-field, data-types

A very basic question.

We define a number type of custom field and try to fetch it in apex. After this suppose I write following code :

```
Set<Integer> validCounts= new Set<Integer>{1,3,6,9};
validCounts.contains(caseRecord.Count__c); //field of type: Number(5,0)
//Gives error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void contains(Decimal)     
//from the type Set<Integer>
```

What is best solution for this:

1. We should define set as `Set<Decimal>` OR
2. Typecast field value to integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is that if `Count__c` is logically always an integer, then your business logic should reflect that.

So stick with `Set<Integer>` and go with e.g.:

```
validCounts.contains(caseRecord.Count__c != null ? caseRecord.Count__c.intValue() : null);
```

This also avoids you (and anyone else maintaining the code in the future) needing to know how sets handle decimals that have different numbers of decimal places.

Comment: Also, from a practical perspective, Decimal uses like 36 bytes of memory, but Integer uses only 4, which can easily be the difference between a heap limit exception or not.

Comment: @sfdcfox I initially posted this trying to tag Keith C but I guess it didn't work maybe because of the space in his username, so reposting again tagging the real master,

I was wondering if there are any differences between using the intValue() method from the Decimal class vs using Integer.valueOf() method and also wouldn't the second one help eliminate the null check? Thanks!

Comment: @Bahman.A In SFSE, you have to ignore any spaces to mention someone (so KeithC to mention Keith). Also, comments on a post automatically notify the creator of the post (in fact, you *can't* mention the post creator explicitly). Aside from that, for your question, yes, Integer.valueOf will work even with null values, so `validCounts.contains(Integer.valueOf(caseRecord.Count__c));` is just as efficient with no risk of NullPointerException.

Comment: @sfdcfox Awesome to know that info about SFSE. and appreciate the quick answer. Thank you, sir!

Comment: @Bahman.A Though, thinking about it, you can also just `validCounts.contains((Integer)caseRecord.Count__c)`, as casting a null value is also okay, and performs better CPU-wise.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. I would like to format the variable based on the field type. Now I am wondering what field types will be true for the 2nd condition (instanceOf Integer) because even the Number type fields are stored as Decimal. For example QuoteLineItem.Quantity prints 2.00 and not 2 in Apex.

There is no Decimal method than can differentiate between 2.00 (Number) and 2.00 (Decimal).

```
if(val instanceOf Decimal || val instanceOf Double) {
  val = Decimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(val)).setScale(2).format();
} else if(val instanceOf Integer) {
  val = Integer.valueOf(val).format();
}
```